# Why does half of a planet's radius end up being the radius of the core?

Tags: planetary-formation, terrestrial-planets

[This answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/22964/9527) makes the assumption that the ratio between the radius of a planet and the radius of its core is roughly constant shortly after planetary formation. Why should this be the case? Do we know why, when a planet forms, it ends up with half of its radius being core?

Comment: Isn't this just based on assuming the same mix of heavy core-forming elements and lighter mantle/crust forming elements? Take any mass of the mix, turn it into a sphere and have a core form, and the ratio should be the same.

Comment: I don't think your linked question/answer makes that assumption for any other than the smaller , inner planets in our system.